# Android Studio - show Java extensions

Tags: android-studio, intellij-idea

I'm not sure when it happened, but somehow I don't see in Android Studio 2.1.3 the Java file extensions in any explorer window anymore. I guess it has to do with the SVN project share (first check-in), because I didn't observe this behaviour before. Instead of `MainActivity.java` I see `MainActivity`.
I don't find any setting where to switch that back. Does anybody know where this setting is?

Comment: I never even saw `.java`. Why do you need it anyway? I do see `.xml` though. :)

Comment: @Vucko Hidden file extensions are confusing and could lead to errors. This is Windows-like and not developer-like.

Comment: I know, I always like to see extensions in windows. Don't know of a way to do it in AS. Java classes have different icon at least ;)

Comment: What do you mean by "in explorer window"? If you mean the Project view, the Project view actually shows Java classes contained in .java files, not the .java files themselves, and classes do not have any extension in their names. There is no option to change that.

Comment: Agree that the full file name and extension should be available in the IDE in at least the Project Files view.
Bug filed:
https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=231985

Comment: Wow, they haven't addressed this bug for 4 years? I am also experiencing this issue but with *.kt files instead.

Answer (score 0):

The closest alternative I have found is installing an icon pack Plugin which gives different file types different icons, I am using Atom Material Icons.

```
File -> Settings -> Plugins-> Search marketplace
```

Its really helpful to see the extensions when working with both Java and Kotlin code.